# F# type of recursive tree structure

Tags: recursion, f#, tree

I am still quite new at F# and trying to figure out how to make my own kind of type that can hold any number of "A"'s before if should how a value in the end.

As an example it could be like:

```
A(A(A(A(A(0))))).
```

if I try to make the type like this I try to declare it like this:

```
type test = 
          | A of int
          | A of test;;
```

It tells me that I can't declare the same type twice as I have duplicates. Is there any way to work around this or do I really need to make the last node another name like this:

```
type test = 
          | B of int
          | A of test;;
```

and the result would then be:

```
A(A(A(A(B(0)))))
```

Any help please?

Comment: One alternative is `type test = A of test option`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will fit your other limitations (which you're not telling us), but this can be easily done by making the type generic:

```
type test<'a> = A of 'a

let a0 = A 0
let a1 = A(A(0))
let a5 = A(A(A(A(A(0)))))
```

This approach has this trait that values with different number of As have different types - i.e. in the above snippet, `a0` has type `test<int>`, but `a1` has type `test<test<int>>`. Whether this is an advantage or a disadvantage depends on your larger context.

That being said, I find myself wondering why you would want to do this in the first place, except as an abstract exercise in language syntax. Perhaps if you clarify your root problem and/or domain, the community would be able to help you better.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was exactly what I was looking for. Had been reading in f# books and alot on the net and simply couldn't find an answer like this. The f# book I have is not very well written in my opinion. Thank you again so much :)!

Comment: If my answer helped you, would you consider accepting it?

Comment: Oh sorry. First time I write a question. Should be done now thank you :)

Comment: @ANACoder - Have you seen http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/ yet? It's the best reference I've found so far. I recommend starting with the [Why use F#?](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/series/why-use-fsharp.html) series, then read whatever other series you'd like. I think you'll learn a lot from that site.

Answer (score 7):

Others have suggested workarounds, but I'd suggest that you really don't want `A(A(A(A(A(0)))))` the way you think you do, and that `A(A(A(A(B(0)))))` (which the language is trying to force you into) is a better choice.

Let's look at your tree type. You have two different kinds of things: a tree node that contains other tree nodes, or a tree node that contains data. What you are trying to do is call those two things by the same name:

```
type test =
          | A of int
          | A of test
```

Those names aren't particularly descriptive. Let's rename them to

```
type Tree =
          | Node of int
          | Node of Tree
```

Now when you're working through your tree structure, you'll need to tell the "Node of int" case apart from the "Node of Tree" case: if it's a "Node of int", you'll want to (say) extract the int and use it in a calculation. But if it's a "Node of Tree", you'll want to (say) dive further into the tree structure to eventually reach the pot of gold at the end of the rainbow... I mean, the int at the end of the tree.

So you'd need to write a `match` structure something like the following:

```
let rec diveTree calculation node =
    match node with
        | Node a -> match a with
                    | :? int -> calculation a
                    | :? Tree -> diveTree calculation a
```

However, what if we did what F# is trying to force you to do, and used *different* names for the "contains an int" and "contains another tree" cases? Then your type would look like:

```
type Tree =
          | LeafNode of int
          | TreeNode of Tree
```

And the `match` structure would look like:

```
let rec diveTree calculation node =
    match node with
        | LeafNode a -> calculation a
        | TreeNode a -> diveTree calculation a
```

I think you'll find the latter much easier to read and understand than the former. And **that** is why F# requires you to use different labels for the different cases of a discriminated union.

Comment: Note that a better design for this would be to make it generic: `type Tree<'a> = LeafNode of 'a | TreeNode of Tree`. Also, the name "tree" isn't quite the right name for this structure since a tree usually has multiple branches at each level (and can hold many different values in its leaf nodes), and this structure only has one branch (and just one leaf node, so it can only hold a single int). But real Tree structures often have the same basic shape, with just a different definition of TreeNode (e.g., `TreeNode of Tree * Tree` for a binary tree). So Tree is a good enough name here.

Comment: Ty for your long answer :) It cleared up alot things as well and it's always nice when people try to help :) This wasn't exactly what I was looking for. I need it to be of the same type. Why I need it to be like this is a longer story to explain :) But again, thanks alot for your answer :)

Comment: "I need it to be of the same type." But in fact, as Fyodor Soikin pointed out in his answer, they're going to be of *different* types. Your leaf nodes will be of type `test<int>` and your tree nodes will be of type `test<test>`. I think this is going to cause you problems. Could you expand your question to explain *why* you want the tree nodes and leaf nodes to be of the same type? I have a feeling that there's a better way to do what you're trying to do, but we can't give you better advice until we know what problem you're *really* trying to solve.